# Best statement to use for FK constraint in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

For FK, should I always insert this statement `ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE` or should it be `ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL`

I have lots of lookups, let's take the continent to country to state to city to neighborhood flow, or the Industry to company to brand to local store flow where the child value is dependent on the parent value. Then there are FK tables like System codes which have a code value used by other tables but do not directly relate to the child.

So I am lost which FK statement to use. My goal is:

- Not to lose child data if parent goes dead.
- Have less or no Joins when jumping between tables.
- Not to delete any data.
- Ensure that if I update one table all the children, grand children, great grandchildren table, etc everyone gets auto updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally avoid cascades, and limit them to where they are a real requirement. You do not plan to delete a continent, do you ?
Let's say we have a classical sample:

- Client --> Orders --> OrderDetails
- Families --> Products --> OrderDetails

I would not allow any cascade, except maybe a cascade delete for Orders->OrderDetails (and only if the business says it is ok to delete an order, which is not sure).
I would, however have a PhasedOut date field in the Products table, to allow a product to disappear from the catalog, but remain in the database, idem for Customers: a customer may disappear, but still remain in the db.

Comment: so Cascade is used only if i want the child to update or delete? if i dont use cascade the child stays as is even if parent dies?

Comment: If you don't use cascade and you try to delete the parent, you will get an error (except if there's no child), which is GOOD. Referential integrity is there to avoid "orphans".